# Looking for a straightforward way to remove a set of rows using Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is there a way to remove a set of rows from a database based on a predicate rule using Entity Framework?

Just an example that does not work:

```
context.entity.remove(i => i.name == "name");
```

The way I am doing today is not straightforward. I would have to loop and remove item by item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use EntityFramework.Extended library.
https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

Example:

```
//delete all users where FirstName matches
context.Users.Delete(u => u.FirstName == "firstname");
```

This approach will not retrieve rows from database.